# I want to have buttons that will add text as plain text on another webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, logging

Basically what I want is to have a webpage that has some buttons. Btn1, Btn2, Btn3. When i click Btn1 I want to have some text writen to log.html . So ex. when i hit Btn1 i want "dd/mm/yy Did that and that" writen on that file.
Thank you.

Comment: keyword to search for - AJAX - good luck

Comment: Thank you very much Jaromanda

Comment: Don't even need ajax. Simple form submit processing would do just fine. But we'd like to see what you tried so far and then, if you still.need help we will take it from there. You will never learn if others write the code for you without you trying anything.

Comment: I read some AJAX docs but they dont seem to actually help me. Cause what i need is not an updater. I dont need something that will update a webpage 's text from a txt or asp ect. .What i want is a button that will create a <div> on another webpage.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>D</title>
<script>
function1(){
document.getElementById("sample1").innerHTML = "Added that";
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="function1()">AddSomethingBtn1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="function2()">AddSomethingBtn2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="function3()">AddSomethingBtn3</button>
<div id="sample1">ddd</div>
</body>
```